# How can I get a percentage field with power pivot?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerquery

This should be a fairly easy question for Power Pivot users since I'm a newbie. I am trying to do the following. After pivoting a table I get a crosstab table like this

```
rating         count of id
A              1
B              2
Grand Total    3
```

You can imagine the original table only has two columns (rating and id) and three rows (1 id for A and two different id's for the B rating). What DAX formula do I have to write in order to create a measure that simply shows

```
rating         percent of id
A              1/3
B              2/3
Grand Total    3/3
```

By 1/3 of course I mean 0.3333, I wrote it like that so that it is clear that I simply want that percent of id is the count for each rating divided by the total count. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide the count for each row by the total count.

```
DIVIDE (
    COUNT ( Table1[ID] ),
    CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Table1[ID] ), ALL ( Table1 ) )
)
```

---

For this particular calculation, you don't have to write DAX though. You can just set it in the Value Field Settings.

```
Summarize Value By  :  Count
Show Values As      :  % of Column Total
```

Comment: Dear Alexis. I already knew about changing the Value Field Settings, but wanted to see how it's done in DAX. I was actually looking more for something with ALLSELECTED instead of ALL (in case I apply a filter), but your answer is good. Thanks

Comment: Yep, you want different versions of  `ALL` for different situations. I just gave the basic structure for the calculation.